# Computing Path Algebra of a Quiver

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, quiver

Let $Q$ be a quiver over defined as follows

[image]

Then $KQ\cong$ $\begin{pmatrix}K&K&K\\0&K&K\\0&0&K\end{pmatrix}$, where $KQ$ is just the path algebra. What the professor did was he just took

$e_1 =\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$,
$e_1 =\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$,
$e_1 =\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$

$\alpha =\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$,
$\beta =\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\0&0&1\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$,

to get $\alpha \beta =\begin{pmatrix}0&0&1\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$,

hence $KQ\cong$ $\begin{pmatrix}K&K&K\\0&K&K\\0&0&K\end{pmatrix}$.

I did not understand what was going on, and I asked him, but he just repeated what he wrote on the board. So could you guys help me to understand what he did?

Thanks,

Comment: Read the equality signs as "maps to", and you will see that they define an isomorphism from $KQ$ to that matrix ring on the right hand side.

Comment: OK, but how did we get $\alpha,\beta$? 

And is it generally true to set $e_i = E_{ii}$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What he did is the following recipe, which works for all quivers whose underlying graph is a tree:

Label the vertices such that the arrows are increasing. Then put $e_i \mapsto E_{ii}$ and the unique path (since underlying graph is a tree) from $i$ to $j$ mapsto $E_{ij}$. One can check easily that this defines an isomorphism. It maps a basis to a basis (of the subalgebra generated by those matrices). And multiplication works as it should: The unique path from $i$ to $j$ to $k$ is mapped to $E_{ij}\cdot E_{jk}=E_{ik}$.

More generally if your quiver is acyclic you can put a vector space of dimension = number of arrows form $i$ to $j$ on position $ij$ and just define multiplication as it should behave.

Comment: Great explanation!!!